# Adhering to Eclipse line width

Tags: eclipse

How do I make it so that eclipse adheres to a specific line width and wraps to the next line? my html spans the whole screen and beyond.

I would like it so that if I put a bunch of html in the editor, each line is 80 chars wide and then goes to the next line if it goes beyond 80 chars for a line

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `Formatting` section in `Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Editor`.